# Max and Min in array using minimum comparisons

Tags: algorithm, c

Is this the most robust and fastest way for finding the min and max out of an array without using STL functions? How can I improve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
system("clear");
int c=9,n[10],max,min,i;
while (c>=0) {
n[c]=random()%100;
printf("%d\n",n[c]);
c--;}c=10;
max=n[0];min=n[1];
for ( i =0; i<c; i++) {
  if(max<n[i])max=n[i];
  else if(min>n[i])min=n[i];
}
printf("\n%d\n%d\n",max,min);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this how it's formatted in your IDE?  There's hardly any indentation here.

Comment: Your edit is incorrect. You're re-using `i` for both the inner and outer `for` loops.

Comment: Yep . I am . What's the problem with it ? Is it decreasing performance ? Is it eating up a lot of memory ? @user1118321

Comment: It doesn't work correctly. The code sets `i` to 0, sets the `min` and `max` values, then sets `i` to 0 again, and through the course of the loop increments it up to `SIZE`. When the inner loop finishes the first time, the outer loop will finish, too. Is that what you intended? If so, why do you have the outer loop?

Comment: Thanks mate . I was being stubborn , sorry for the obnoxious comment @user1118321

Comment: @Italian Do **not** edit the code in the question.

Comment: Consistent indenting of the code, a bit of horizontal spacing, and a blank line around code blocks makes the code much more readable/understandable by us humans and does not slow down the execution at all.   Strongly suggest applying such spacing to your code.

Comment: the `printf()` function is expensive for time.  to speed up the execution: Suggest considering not printing the elements of the array or only calling once with all the elements printed in one call

Comment: the posted code contains some `magic` numbers.  the use of `magic` numbers makes code more difficult to understand/debug/maintain.   Suggest using a #define with a meaningful name, then use that meaningful name throughout the code.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, format your code. Indentation goes along way. If everything is left-justified, you can't make out any of the logic.

Secondly, this is a good idea:

```
max=n[0];min=n[1];
```

But we should really initialize both to `n[0]`, and on separate lines:

```
max = n[0];
min = n[0];
```

The reason is this allows us to start at index 1:

```
for (i=1; i<c; ++i) {
    if (n[i] > max) {
        max = n[i];
    }
    else if (n[i] < min) {
        min = n[i];
    }
}
```

We could also consider putting this into a function:

```
void minmax(int* arr, int len, int* min, int* max) { ... }

minmax(n, c, &min, &max);
```

Any time you're doing something `k` times for some constant, or filling in an array - do it front to back. It will be much easier to understand. Don't fill `n` from index 9 to 0... fill it from 0 to 9. Also, prefer a `for` loop to a `while` loop and use `i` both times:

```
int c=10, n[10];
for (i=0; i<c; ++i) {
}
```

And lastly, `c` is a bad name for the max size of your array. Something like `SIZE` or `LENGTH` or anything to that effect would be better.

Comment: I agree with your points, but on the last one, I'd argue that `SIZE` and `LENGTH` are only slightly less meaningless than `c`. Size of what? Length of what? In what units? Perhaps `NUM_VALUES`? (I also hate `value`, but this is an exercise, so the values have no real meaning. If they were grades, or dollar amounts, or something, I'd suggest `NUM_GRADES`, or `NUM_DOLLARS` or something like that.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the most robust and fastest way for finding the min and max
>   out of an array without using STL functions?

You tagged your question [c](/questions/tagged/c), but [`STL` is a part of `C++`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library).

Your `random()` is not really *random*. See what `man random` says:

> If no seed value is provided, the random() function is automatically
>   seeded with a value of 1.

You didn't provide a seed so `random()` returns the same numbers at every run.

You don't use `int argc, char const *argv[]` parameters and you can safely remove them. Both `clang` and `gcc` inform about this with `-Wextra` flag:

```
main.c:3:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
main.c:3:32: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code incorporates the comments,

cleanly compiles

performs the desired actions

and is about a quick as I know how to do it.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_VALUES (10)

int main( void )
{
    system("clear");


    int n[MAX_VALUES];
    int max;
    int min;
    int i;

    srandom( time(NULL) );

    for( i = 0; i < MAX_VALUES; i++ )
    {
        n[i] = random()%100;
    }


    max=n[0];
    min=n[0];

    for ( i=1; i<MAX_VALUES; i++)
    {
        if(max<n[i]) max=n[i];
        else if(min>n[i]) min=n[i];
    }

     printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n min: %d, max: %d",
         n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3], n[4], n[5], n[6], n[7], n[8], n[9], min, max );
    return 0;
}
```